# Modify multiple lightning:recordeditform fields before firing form.submit() method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, aura, lightning-recordeditform

I have Parent Component(to save Account record ) and Child Component(to save contact records).
In parent component I have submit button.  
 In both of the components I'm using **lightning:recordEditform** to save records. Whenever click on the below button account record will be saved.

Parent Comp:

```
 <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
     
    <div aura:id="mainpage" class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
        <lightning:card  title="{!v.title}"  class="slds-text-align_left">
            <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="myRecordForm"  objectApiName="Account" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" >      <lightning:messages />
                    <div class="slds-grid">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-p-around_medium" style="width: 75%">
                            <lightning:inputField  fieldName="Name" variant="label-hidden" />
                        </div>
                      
                            <c:childComponent aura:id="childComponent"  iterationList = "{!v.iterationList}" /> 
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="slds-float--right" style="padding-right: 2%">
                        <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" variant="brand" label="Save" title="Save" type="submit"  />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </lightning:recordEditForm>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Using **onSuccess** method in Parent component, am firing **aura:method** to pass parent recordId (Inserted AccountId) to child component and by using this controller method to fire the onSubmit method of child records. 
And calling child component method to save child component records.

Aura:method fired from OnSuccess in parent component:
Parent Controller:

```
 handleSuccess :  function(component, event, helper) {
        var childCmp = component.find("childComponent");
        var returnvalue = childCmp.GetAccountID(record.id);    
    },
```

Child Comp:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
   <aura:method name="getAccountId" action="{!c.saveRecords}"  access="public">
        <aura:attribute name="AccountId" type="String"  />
    </aura:method>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Items}" var="item">
        <lightning:recordEditForm  objectApiName="Contact">
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstNAme" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="UnitPrice" />
           
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </aura:iteration> 
</aura:component>
```

Child Controller:

```
saveRecords : function(component, event) {
       var params = event.getParam('arguments');
        if (params) {
            var param1 = params.AccountId;
            var editForms = component.find('editForm');
            var forms = [].concat(editForms || []);
            forms.forEach((form)=>{ 
            // using below logic trying to update record values before saving each contact record
                event.preventDefault();
                var fields = event.getParam('fields'); 
                fields["AccountId"] = param1; 
                form.submit();
            });     
            } 
     }
```

My requirement is to update multiple lightning:recordEditforms before submitting to database.
Here am unable to modify record values. It is not throwing any errors and not saving record.

Can anyone help on this, what is the mistake here.
Thank you

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You're trying to build a UI using the wrong tools. The various lightning record forms are not meant for bulk creating/updating records, nor can you interact with their data except when the form is submitted. You will need to take a different approach.

Comment: Yay i have agreed with @sfdcfox. I feel go with apex controller while creating multiple records also it would be easy to handle if you get any exceptions.